# Parse JS object for processing in PHP same file

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I have learning javascript and a little bit stuck. I have a JS object created that recieves information from various urls/ workloads. I want to take this JS object and further process it in PHP(write to csv etc). However I don't know how to get the object out of JS and into my php. I have everything in the one file and Im not sure if thats my issue alot of solutions have seen have filegetcontents etc. I can paste in my code. Be kind I am an ambitious learner but sometimes get so stuck I have googled extensively perhaps not the right things though. I have read suggestions about parsing but I haven;t had luck making it work in the one file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /tests occurance of keyword
const before3 = new Date(); 
let xhttp3 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp3.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var c = JSON.parse(this.response);
        resultcount3 = c.answer;
        console.log(resultcount3);
        const now3 = new Date();
        diff3 =now3-before3;

        //check = occurance of key word in string
       
        function countWordAppearance(string, word){
            return string.split(word).length-1;
        }
        resultLocal3=countWordAppearance(paragraph.toLowerCase(),word.toLowerCase());

        console.log("this result 3" +resultLocal3);
   
        if (resultcount3===resultLocal3){
            test3 ='Passed';
        } else {
            test3 = 'Failed';
        }
        console.log("Paragraph :" +paragraph + " word :" + word + " result " + resultLocal3 + " Response Time (milliseconds) :"+ diff3);
        var testKeyWordAppearance = {
            "paragraph": paragraph,
            "word": word,
            "result Local": resultLocal3,
            "result": resultcount3,
            "responseT": diff3,
            "Test" : test3
        };
        console.log(testKeyWordAppearance);

        //var json_kwc =$parseJson(testKeyWordAppearance);
        //$.post("testcorrectness.php", {obj:json_kwc});
    } 
};

xhttp3.open("GET",proxyURL+"?service="+3 +"&paragraph="+paragraph+"&&word="+word);
xhttp3.send();



</script>

<?php

//$mygetter = $_POST['obj'];
//$values = json_decode($mygetter);
//echo $values;

?>
```

Comment: This will break your javascript `/tests occurance of keyword` use two slashes instead `//`

Comment: The JavaScript code you've posted is using `GET` to send arbitrary text. I'd suggest you use `POST` for that. The PHP that you've commented out looks for data in `$_POST`, but it's expecting JSON and you're sending form-encoded data. I suggest you simplify things to concentrate only on passing data to PHP, and add the rest later. Look at using [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) rather than XMLHTTPRequest.

Comment: Note also that many things can be done in the browser with JavaScript. Find the right libraries and  you might not need the server at all.